# How to remove a field from a form in the Sylius admin backend?

Tags: symfony4, symfony-forms, sylius, form-fields

I'm working on a Sylius application and want to remove a form in the admin backend.

In this special case it's the field `on_hand` (in the `ProductVariant` creation and update context), that shouldn't be available. (Since we get that information from suppliers directly and import it automatically into the database.) I've already found the correct template (`/vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/views/ProductVariant/Tab/_inventory.html.twig`), created a copy in my app and removed the field from the view. But its still in the form object. I could not find it in any form. It seems to be generated, but I don't see where this generation takes place and how to exclude this field from the form generation.

**How to remove the field `on_hand` and remove it?**

How to handle such cases in general and find and remove fields from forms, provided by Sylius?

---

The docu article "[Customizing Forms](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.8/customization/form.html)" says:

> You can:
>
> - add completely new fields,
> - modify existing fields, make them required, change their HTML class, change labels etc.,
> - remove fields that are not used.

...and shows, what to do, "*if you are planning to add new fields*". But it doesn't explain, how to remove fields -- and it seems to be a bit more complicated than adding.

---

What I tried so far:

```
final class ProductVariantTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            // ->add(...)
            // ...
            ->remove('onHand')
        ;
    }
    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [BaseProductVariantType::class];
    }
}
```

But the `remove(...)` call seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```php
final class ProductVariantTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            // ->add(...)
            // ...
            ->remove('onHand')
        ;
    }
    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [BaseProductVariantType::class];
    }
}
```

was correct, it also was not being ignored. The problem was, that at this place / point of time the `Form` is not completed yet: The field `onHand` is not there, so attempts to remove it cannot have any effect, since it's being added later. The trick is to defer the processing of the `ProductVariantTypeExtension`. It's easily done by setting the `priority`:

**`/config/services.yaml`**

```yaml
...
parameters:
    ...
    services:
        ...
            App\Form\Extension\ProductVariantTypeExtension:
                tags:
                    - { name: 'form.type_extension', extended_type: 'Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Form\Type\ProductVariantType', priority: -1 }
```